# Sumif function to add smallest number

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to add the smallest number out of one row 1 in Column O through R. I would then like to add the number found (smallest) to the value in column S. What formula is used? I know its complicated but I almost have it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may help you out, although it doesn't use sumif. I hope I had the right idea:

=SUM(MIN(O1:R1)+S1)

Comment: Could you mark the question as answered please?